# write special exception message for try catch during Inserting in a MySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, try-catch

I want to insert information in a MySQL table based on the following code:

```
public void writeMapDocNameToDocId(File file, ArrayList<String> docNames) {
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt= null;
            try{
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                String query = " insert into DocumentNameId (docName)"
                        + " values (?)";
                preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                int i=0;


                for (String docName : docNames) 
                { 
                    preparedStmt.setString (1, docName);
                    preparedStmt.addBatch();
                    i++;
                    if (i % 1000 == 0 || i == docNames.size()) {
                        preparedStmt.executeBatch(); 
                    }
                }
                conn.commit();
                preparedStmt.close();
                conn.setAutoCommit(true);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

I got the following error for some of the DocName.

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'docName' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1269)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:955)
    at dataLayer.RepositorySQL.writeMapDocNameToDocId(RepositorySQL.java:508)
```

I want to know which docNames cause this error but I don't know how should I write message in catch that show me the docName.Since, docName is undefined in catch body.

I am not an expert in java and MySQLso my code could be based on wrong foundations. Please help me to understand my mistakes

Comment: The easiest from what you've already got is to move your declaration of `i` outside of the `try` and then once in the exception, use the value of `i` to ascertain which element in your array caused the error.

Comment: Print out the `docName` as you go through the loop. Or that is even better ^

Comment: @3kings I tried that but it is part of code and this function call from more complicated class and the number of time this function is call is more than 100000 times.

Comment: Try @CubeJockey way. That seems much easier and better.

Comment: You're welcome @Suri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an illustration in code, based on my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34051674/write-special-exception-message-for-try-catch-during-inserting-in-a-mysql-table#comment55857809_34051674) above:

```
int i=0; //Declare i outside of your try-catch statement

try{
    ...
    for (String docName : docNames){ 
        preparedStmt.setString (1, docName);
        preparedStmt.addBatch();
        i++;
        if (i % 1000 == 0 || i == docNames.size()) {
            preparedStmt.executeBatch(); 
        }
    }
    ...
}
catch(Exception e){

    String docNameError = docNames.get(i - 1); 
    //subtract 1 from i, because i is only incremented after a successful add 
    //to your prepared statement.

    //use docNameError however you'd like to report the exception

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Alternatively, you could increment `i` at the start of each iteration of your `for-each` loop, to avoid the subtraction in your catch:

```
for (String docName : docNames){
    i++;
    preparedStmt.setString(1,docName);
```